# Set an scaled image rectangle coordinates

Tags: monogame, windows-phone-8

I have used the Origin parameter to draw the image (the image is also scaled) in center of the screen, and created a rectangle to detect whether user tapped on that image.
The problem is that if I tap on left part of the image it doesn't happen anything but at the right part, it executes what it has to.

How can i fix this? I have tried something but any result...

```
ItemRectangle[ItemID] = new Rectangle((int)Position.X + (int)(Position.X * Scales), (int)Position.Y + (int)(Position.Y * Scales), ItemTexture[ItemID].Width, ItemTexture[ItemID].Height);

spriteBatch.Draw(ItemTexture[i], ItemPosition[i], null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(ItemTexture[i].Width / 2, ItemTexture[i].Height / 2), Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Comment: why do you use `(int)Position.X + (int)(Position.X * Scales)` instead of `Position.X` ?

Comment: because I tried to fix my problem by summing the image position and it's scale. schematically --|---- that is my image. When I tap the portion image before | i get no response, but after | it is working. This is because of scale and origin, and I do not know how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to draw a rectangle in the middle of the screen and scale it you could do it this way:

```
Texture2D rectTexture;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
Vector2 scaleVector = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
Vector2 screenSizeVector = new Vector2(screenWidth, screenHeight);

spriteBatch.Draw(rectTexture, new Vector2(rect.X, rect.Y) + 
     new Vector2(rect.width/2, rect.height/2) + screenSizeVector/2, null, Color.White,
     0f, Vector2.Zero, scaleVector , SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

And then you would have to scale the width and height of the rect when you are checking the user's inputs like this

```
Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width*ScaleVector.X, height*ScaleVector.Y);
```